# Use User Service in Openfire to Register new user via xmpp framework for iOS

Tags: ios, web-services, openfire, xmppframework, user-registration

I can see now the users manually created in my openfire server, i am working with a book to achieve this but, there is a way the programmer register a user via http using the openfire and the user service plugin. I want to know how to register a new user with this feature and if i can check if the user already exists on the openfire server with my iOS application. How can i get the http link of my openfire to achieve a registration or is there another way? i read that for custom registration it would be good to create a webservice but i know very little about webservices so please anyone can help, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a user by creating an NSXMLElement and pass it to the xmppstream to register new user.Make sure you have xmppstream object so that you are able to fire your queries to server and get the required output.

```
NSMutableArray *elements = [NSMutableArray array];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"username" stringValue:@"abc"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"password" stringValue:@"xyz"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"abc"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"email" stringValue:@"abc@xyz.com"]];
[self.xmppStream registerWithElements:elements error:nil];
[self connect];
```

This will register a new user or in-case the user already exists on your server it gives you an error in received iq.

Comment: Hi @skaur thanks for the answer! i will check this out! what fields are mandatory in order to correctly register a user? And another question that i have, now i can connect and give presence to the openfire server, i commit the autofetch roster but i am not getting it, i am using the coredatarosterstorage implemented in the xmpp framework, how can i verify if the roster is correctly populated? i am not getting the friends of the account!

Comment: Hi @user3741129,you can request the registration fields from your server.This is the XML query to get the registration fields:<iq type='get' id='reg1' to='shakespeare.lit'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'/></iq>
NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:register"];
NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"admin@domain/xmppframework"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"domain"];
[iq addChild:query];
[self.xmppStream sendElement:iq];

Comment: also you can check on your openfire server when you create new user, the required fields are marked by * but you don't need to enter confirm password when registering new user from code.

Answer (score 0):

This solution HAS WORKED for me. A more organised approch

```
NSString *username = @"rohit@XMPP_SERVER_IP_HERE"; // OR [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",username,XMPP_BASE_URL]]
NSString *password = @"SOME_PASSWORD";

AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

del.xmppStream.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:username];

NSLog(@"Does supports registration %ub ", );
NSLog(@"Attempting registration for username %@",del.xmppStream.myJID.bare);

if (del.xmppStream.supportsInBandRegistration) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![del.xmppStream registerWithPassword:password error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Oops, I forgot something: %@", error);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No Error");
    }
}

// You will get delegate called after registrations in either success or failure case. These delegates are in XMPPStream class
// - (void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender
//- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement *)error
```